# In ggplot, how do you do match geom_text to reordered box plots based on third variable with custom labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just trying to add my CLD values to box plots. The box plots are reordered based on the descending order of a third variable, and have custom x-axis labels.

I have data that looks like this;

```
df<-structure(list(Cross = c("CBG X CBG", "CBG X CBG", "SDZ X SDZ", 
"SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", 
"SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", 
"SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", 
"SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", 
"SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", 
"SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", 
"SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X SDZ", "USBG2 X USBG2", 
"USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", 
"USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", 
"USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", 
"USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", 
"USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", 
"USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", 
"USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", 
"USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", 
"USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", 
"USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", 
"USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", 
"USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG1", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG1 X USBG2", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", 
"NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", 
"NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", 
"NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", 
"NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", 
"NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", 
"NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X USBG2", 
"NTBG X USBG2", "NTBG X USBG2", "NTBG X USBG2", "NTBG X USBG2", 
"NTBG X USBG2", "NTBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", 
"CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", 
"CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", "CBG X USBG2", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG1", 
"CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", 
"CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", 
"CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", 
"CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", 
"CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", 
"CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG1", "USBG1 X UCBG", 
"USBG1 X UCBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", 
"SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", 
"SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", 
"SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", 
"SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", 
"SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X CBG", "NTBG X SDZ", "NTBG X SDZ", "NTBG X SDZ", 
"NTBG X SDZ", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", 
"SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", 
"SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", 
"SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", 
"SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", 
"SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG1", 
"SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"SDZ X USBG2", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X UCBG", 
"CBG X UCBG", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X UCBG", 
"CBG X UCBG"), Relatedness = c(0.42, 0.42, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 
0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 
0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, 
-0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, 
-0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, 
-0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, 
-0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, 
-0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, 
-0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, 
-0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.06, -0.06, 
-0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, 
-0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, 
-0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.12, 
-0.12, -0.12, -0.12, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, 
-0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, 
-0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.19, -0.24, -0.24, 
-0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, 
-0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, 
-0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, 
-0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, 
-0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.24, -0.28, -0.28, 
-0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28, -0.28), Rel.factor = structure(c(17L, 
17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("-0.28", "-0.24", "-0.19", "-0.17", "-0.12", 
"-0.09", "-0.06", "-0.04", "-0.01", "0.02", "0.11", "0.24", "0.25", 
"0.3", "0.38", "0.4", "0.42"), class = "factor"), Height = c(17, 
48.09, 4.2, 5.24, 12.36, 3.94, 10.68, 29.01, 28.81, 16.27, 20.88, 
43.36, 20.75, 64.02, 60.88, 37.18, 98.18, 32.64, 71.19, 48.24, 
67.24, 55.97, 60.15, 92.95, 116.2, 51.51, 50.46, 117.01, 91.83, 
73.32, 115.73, 100.92, 117.61, 93.29, 123.53, 121.25, 83.48, 
7.49, 6.38, 72.12, 54.65, 53.05, 58.83, 24.59, 31.4, 31.72, 46.81, 
80.44, 65.76, 39.52, 69.2, 37.55, 42.55, 85.97, 77.42, 44.86, 
54.91, 71.82, 52.13, 84.49, 105.67, 80.6, 101.15, 138.11, 15.64, 
5.9, 41.9, 59.64, 52.54, 63.8, 48.63, 40.89, 71.46, 20.96, 63.27, 
40.46, 69.35, 91.03, 63.03, 95.8, 67.81, 67.35, 82.9, 64.46, 
58.12, 58.68, 17.08, 17.9, 8.87, 35.18, 15.67, 27.46, 15.66, 
15.81, 30.17, 33.84, 32.81, 30.47, 24.46, 43.44, 57.03, 66.62, 
68.14, 79.81, 47.23, 60.01, 79.93, 63.76, 43.45, 38.83, 43.8, 
63.29, 49.6, 90.85, 71.58, 74.56, 54.28, 97.1, 123.8, 93.69, 
88.88, 76.03, 116.95, 107.46, 8.32, 9.35, 12.73, 33.51, 4, 21.05, 
7.83, 27.48, 30.07, 14.47, 51.6, 20.59, 21.64, 16.81, 32.58, 
50.26, 54.03, 54.89, 54.39, 44.43, 69.19, 45.41, 55.77, 76.78, 
26.28, 41.25, 71.18, 40.6, 99.85, 124.26, 67.4, 17.86, 16.99, 
29.21, 20.64, 34.36, 23.91, 22.42, 4.19, 5.71, 8.48, 43.72, 33.61, 
67.1, 56.19, 44.59, 65.32, 82.4, 82.69, 62.88, 43.76, 51.84, 
52.29, 10.1, 19.04, 20.54, 29.11, 8.92, 5.89, 16.26, 15.81, 11.5, 
54.22, 40.45, 42.05, 18.36, 49.19, 47.04, 79.76, 41.2, 24.4, 
29.55, 49.56, 24.2, 92.97, 66.3, 64.77, 37.32, 64.4, 36.44, 76.31, 
40.5, 80.8, 70.6, 91.09, 66.11, 3.92, 17.52, 2.54, 22, 32.42, 
12.85, 26.2, 50.37, 43.12, 70.67, 70.97, 73.68, 37.17, 47.92, 
67.44, 31.11, 61.12, 86.2, 67.47, 60.34, 82.8, 99.28, 52.27, 
73.8, 88.83, 80.55, 75.01, 127.78, 8.57, 4.27, 56.35, 21.25, 
35.82, 83.99, 40.43, 39.2, 22.02, 19.06, 57.7, 55.14, 43, 45.65, 
43.79, 89.78, 111.48, 76.47, 79.78, 54.49, 88.26, 77.43, 76.36, 
91.32, 67.6, 93.98, 91.5, 123.62, 15.26, 106.06, 73.14, 72.41, 
49.26, 95.98, 91.77, 47.41, 24.82, 59.59, 27.32, 33.52, 63.33, 
48.97, 92.02, 106.54, 89.93, 92.77, 86.63, 61.51, 89.31, 68.08, 
104.8, 67.29, 51.68, 83.43, 44.06, 112.81, 104.65, 106.47, 104.01, 
107.48, 64.05, 70.5, 69.56, 106.18, 79.87, 79.82, 75.62, 120, 
115.47, 115.57, 147.35, 87.44, 97.78, 108.06, 92.71, 141.6, 101.56, 
121.34, 124.83, 115.3, 121.46, 128.89, 88.37, 94.98, 133.51, 
125.07, 114.61, 59.12, 143.01, 110.53, 60.85, 138.78, 159.24, 
155.5, 1.45, 25.91, 81.29, 64.51, 63.45, 55.5, 65.56, 94.1, 32.73, 
56.79, 86.98, 86.35, 65.08, 59, 76.96, 54.03, 57, 53.37, 101.52, 
94.3, 107.33, 76.22, 72.85, 32.29, 12.6, 10.49, 12.24, 12.48, 
32.94, 7.55, 25.19, 47.2, 52.52, 45.41, 21.96, 48.65, 57.03, 
42.43, 52.89, 23.13, 31.22, 47.38, 63.77, 59.79, 67, 42.02, 26.09, 
31.02, 92.87, 89.03, 77.3, 68.24, 63.16, 75.35, 75.06, 94.89, 
85, 65.16, 89.48, 90.43, 68.74, 55.3, 86.71, 68.55, 75.56, 44.98, 
84.63, 94.75, 16.46, 41.14, 7.6, 40.72, 48.8, 81.26, 96.59, 67.74, 
85.94, 97.11)), row.names = c(NA, -410L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My summary and CLD values look like this;

```
df.sum<-structure(list(Cross = c("CBG X CBG", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X USBG1", 
"CBG X USBG2", "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X SDZ", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG2", 
"SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG2", 
"USBG1 X UCBG", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2"
), Relatedness = c(0.42, -0.28, -0.04, 0.02, 0.24, -0.12, -0.01, 
0.11, -0.09, 0.4, -0.17, -0.19, -0.24, -0.06, 0.3, 0.25, 0.38
), Rel.factor = structure(c(17L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 
6L, 16L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 14L, 13L, 15L), .Label = c("-0.28", 
"-0.24", "-0.19", "-0.17", "-0.12", "-0.09", "-0.06", "-0.04", 
"-0.01", "0.02", "0.11", "0.24", "0.25", "0.3", "0.38", "0.4", 
"0.42"), class = "factor"), n = c(2L, 10L, 28L, 12L, 31L, 4L, 
36L, 7L, 26L, 35L, 62L, 23L, 45L, 2L, 22L, 38L, 27L), Mean.height = c(32.545, 
58.336, 55.9053571428571, 46.4066666666667, 41.5483870967742, 
66.7175, 43.6847222222222, 23.6271428571429, 64.8257692307692, 
61.1508571428571, 93.2898387096774, 66.6208695652174, 54.4551111111111, 
6.42, 56.5281818181818, 55.4078947368421, 59.97), sd.height = c(21.9839498270898, 
32.2618103094734, 30.329989496053, 28.3102674382324, 28.0006307187028, 
37.7242613137311, 24.3547219811226, 6.24679041397984, 28.0167527273347, 
38.5679274993697, 31.7287500330865, 24.7068915511154, 26.1159727876728, 
3.04055915910216, 22.4408230551809, 30.4903842314789, 29.7461798452274
), height.3q = c(`75%` = 40.3175, `75%` = 84.77, `75%` = 74.1025, 
`75%` = 65.765, `75%` = 54.64, `75%` = 81.37, `75%` = 64.4925, 
`75%` = 26.56, `75%` = 87.1925, `75%` = 93.12, `75%` = 115.1275, 
`75%` = 83.82, `75%` = 75.35, `75%` = 7.495, `75%` = 67.695, 
`75%` = 75.6625, `75%` = 78.93), Mean.width = c(7.58, 11.058, 
10.8089285714286, 9.8325, 9.59709677419355, 12.3275, 8.93805555555556, 
6.91714285714286, 12.1138461538462, 10.8597142857143, 12.0629032258065, 
12.2504347826087, 10.2477777777778, 3.525, 10.7818181818182, 
10.1423684210526, 11.5074074074074), sd.width = c(3.88908729652601, 
5.52200406454839, 5.24339255408085, 5.10901542729748, 4.82402887881653, 
5.31163738094636, 4.26402547529541, 1.61882379405248, 4.20342058511691, 
5.57155986486111, 4.29947933832053, 4.92780836243832, 4.45136643417649, 
0.530330085889911, 3.72253707182108, 4.00571782831204, 5.18810443566122
), width.3q = c(`75%` = 8.955, `75%` = 15.45, `75%` = 14.905, 
`75%` = 14.02, `75%` = 12.925, `75%` = 15.0675, `75%` = 11.0775, 
`75%` = 7.44, `75%` = 15.4, `75%` = 15.635, `75%` = 14.24, `75%` = 15.82, 
`75%` = 14.25, `75%` = 3.7125, `75%` = 13.1875, `75%` = 13.2475, 
`75%` = 15.31), Mean.leaves = c(6, 5.9, 6.21428571428571, 5.83333333333333, 
4.7, 6, 4.63888888888889, 4, 5.84615384615385, 7.22857142857143, 
7.56451612903226, 7.69565217391304, 6.31111111111111, 3, 7.45454545454545, 
7.31578947368421, 7.18518518518519), sd.leaves = c(1.4142135623731, 
1.59513148186739, 2.79360569949175, 2.48022481874429, 2.62809751564209, 
1.4142135623731, 1.64147630029935, 0.816496580927726, 2.39486630428185, 
3.30850698765999, 2.44695171853683, 1.66336959782615, 2.20353251747179, 
0, 2.59536716784557, 2.85794542680383, 3.91286868046211), Leaves.3q = c(`75%` = 6.5, 
`75%` = 7, `75%` = 8, `75%` = 7.25, `75%` = 5, `75%` = 7, `75%` = 6, 
`75%` = 4.5, `75%` = 7, `75%` = 9, `75%` = 9, `75%` = 8, `75%` = 8, 
`75%` = 3, `75%` = 8, `75%` = 10, `75%` = 7.5), cld.ht = c("ab", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "ab", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), groups = structure(list(
    Cross = c("CBG X CBG", "CBG X UCBG", "CBG X USBG1", "CBG X USBG2", 
    "NTBG X CBG", "NTBG X SDZ", "NTBG X USBG1", "NTBG X USBG2", 
    "SDZ X CBG", "SDZ X SDZ", "SDZ X UCBG", "SDZ X USBG1", "SDZ X USBG2", 
    "USBG1 X UCBG", "USBG1 X USBG1", "USBG1 X USBG2", "USBG2 X USBG2"
    ), Relatedness = c(0.42, -0.28, -0.04, 0.02, 0.24, -0.12, 
    -0.01, 0.11, -0.09, 0.4, -0.17, -0.19, -0.24, -0.06, 0.3, 
    0.25, 0.38), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
        7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -17L), .drop = TRUE))
```

My custom labels look like this, and match the order of the expected plot order;
**EDIT: Deleted unused label **

```
bi.labels<-c('CBG\nX\nCBG', 'SDZ\nX\nSDZ', 'USBG2\nX\nUSBG2', 'USBG1\nX\nUSBG1',
             'USBG1\nX\nUSBG2', 'NTBG\nX\nCBG', 'NTBG\nX\nUSBG2','CBG\nX\nUSBG2',
             'NTBG\nX\nUSBG1', 'CBG\nX\nUSBG1', 'USBG1\nX\nUCBG', 'SDZ\nX\nCBG',
             'NTBG\nX\nSDZ', 'SDZ\nX\nUCBG',
             'SDZ\nX\nUSBG1', 'SDZ\nX\nUSBG2', 'CBG\nX\nUCBG')
```

Now, I am trying to graph like this;

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Rel.factor, y = Height)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=rev, labels = bi.labels) +
  labs(y = "Height", x = "Cross") +
  #theme_classic(base_size = 12) +
  geom_text(data = df.sum, aes(x = Rel.factor, y = height.3q, label = cld.ht, size = 3.5, vjust=-0.3, hjust =-0.25))
```

I am expecting a graph where box plots are ordered in descending (high to low) order of "Rel.factor", and where the CLDs match their respective "Cross", and my custom label names also match the corresponding "Cross". I feel like maybe I am overcomplicating this, which I am good at : ) Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it true that the length of Cross in the `bi.labels` is 18 but in `df.sum` is 17?

Comment: @SALAR, I just checked and yet it true (I had not noticed this). Cross == "USBG2 X UCBG" never made it to this stage of the experiment so it can be deleted.

Comment: I think the problem was this. So you must get the expected plot now by deleting extra label from `bi.labels`

Comment: I think that fixed it, perhaps?  When I plot with the fixed `bi.labels` vector, it seems to have it plotted from high-to-low `Rel.factor` value on the x axis.  If you remove `labels=bi.labels` from `scale_x_discrete()` (but keep `limits=rev`), you get the correct order you seem to want.  All good?  Was this kind of a typo?

Comment: SALAR and chemdork123, Yes, it seems to magically be working now. I don't understand because before I could have sworn that the text was not matching up. If you want to post it as an answer I will mark it correct.